# Wrong line spacing when changing the font size inside of a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

i'm trying to change the font size inside of a rectangle and always the line space between the last and the second last line is getting wrong. How can that be fixed?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text centered, thick, node distance = 2cm, text width=1cm]   
    \node[block]                (init)  {1 \\  2 \\ 3  \\ 4};
    \node[block,right of=init]  (second){\scriptsize 1 \\ 2 \\ 3  \\ 4};
    \node[block,right of=second](third) {1 \\ \scriptsize 2 \\ 3  \\ 4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Workaround that works. When changing the fontsize for the entire node, I prefer using the `font` option instead.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text centered, thick, node distance = 2cm, text width=1cm]   
    \node[block]                (init)  {1 \\  2 \\ 3  \\ 4};
    \node[block,right of=init,font=\scriptsize]  (second){1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4};
    \node[block,right of=second,font=\scriptsize](third) {{\normalsize 1} \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the rows in a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand{\mylist}[2][]{#1\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text centered, thick, 
                         node distance = 2cm, text width=1cm]
    \node[block]                (init)  {\mylist{1 \\  2 \\ 3  \\ 4}};
    \node[block,right of=init]  (second){\mylist[\scriptsize]{1 \\ 2 \\ 3  \\ 4}};
    \node[block,right of=second](third) {\mylist[\scriptsize]{\normalsize 1 \\ 2 \\ 3  \\ 4}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The optional argument is the "global" size, that you can override for single rows.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the solution of Torbjørn T. but I would like to understand why the option `font` works ?

Another possibility is

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, text centered, thick, 
    node distance = 2cm, 
    text width=1cm]   
    \node[block]                (init)  {1 \\  2 \\ 3  \\ 4};
    \node[block,right of=init]  (second){{\scriptsize 1} \\{\normalsize 2}\\{\scriptsize 3}\\{\normalsize4 }\vfill};
    \node[block,right of=second](third) {1 \\ \scriptsize 2 \\ 3  \\ 4\vfill};
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeah, I would like to know that myself. I just tried it, and found that it worked, but *why* it works, I can't say.

Comment: It must be the way LaTeX treats paragraphs that's causing it. If I recall correctly the default line spacing is the same for an entire paragraph and depends on the text size at the start of the paragraph. When not using the `font` command the text size is changed after the paragraph is started and hence the line spacing is not changed.